# Ruby не понимает метод < и > когда дело касается содержимого массива

Tags: массивы, ruby, методы

Хотел чтобы цикл шел до тех пор, пока значение hp в массиве не упадет до 0 или меньше, но код работает только при **==** или **!=** Если вписать после while **>=** или **>** выдает ошибку:
G:/ruby/mob.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method` >' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Подскажите что не так.
Вот сам код:

```
    Mass = [hp=10]
    puts 'damage'
     while Mass[hp] > 0
    dmg = gets.chomp
    Mass.pop hp
    hp = hp-dmg.to_i
    Mass.push hp
    puts Mass.to_s + ' HP left'
     end
    puts 'mob is dead'
```

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать в этом коде? В первой строке вы получаете массив `Mass` с одним элементом - `[10]`. В третьей строке вы пытаетесь взять его 10-й элемент, там конечно же пусто, то есть вы пытаетесь вызвать сравнение на `nil` и закономерно получаете ошибку. Зачем вам вообще массив,  почему просто не вычитать урон из hp?

Comment: Ну допустим в массиве будет не только хп, а еще куча всего. Это просто тестовый кусок кода. Я пытаюсь взять из массива hp, провести с ним операцию и положить новое значение hp назад в массив. И чтобы цикл завершился когда значение упадет до нуля или ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен хэш, а не массив. В него вы может сложить все нужные вам данные под ключами и работать с ними

```
mob = {hp: 10}
puts 'damage'
while mob[:hp] > 0
  damage = gets.chomp
  mob[:hp] -= damage.to_i
  puts "#{mob[:hp]} HP left"
end
puts 'mob is dead'
```